# Data transfer with tabs to ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am trying to use ViewPager and TabLayout in different ways than the usual.
I have 5 tabs, and each tabs have ViewPager which has two fragment pages (A Fragment and B Fragment)each.

For each tab, ViewPager needs to display same fragment pages with different information. ( Such as Tab's title is displayed in A Fragment, and Tab 1's title is "Android", and Tab 2's title is "IOS" )

Since FragmentPagerAdapter sets the Fragments in **getItem(int position)** method like the below, I tried to send these information in that method (information about the tab).

I found the problem,when i launch the ViewPager and set the adapter to it, the adapter is only stetted once So, when Tab 1's ViewPager already set to A Fragment the title of "Android", it won't change to "IOS" when I turn it to second tab Tab2.

Is there any way sending different informations each tab to the ViewPager to receive the information differently?

I kind of wrote it too broad maybe? if you need more specific informations, or do not get the question please tell me I will explain you more.

Thanks for helping

My FragmentPagerAdapter

```
public class ManagerPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

....

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position){

          ...

          /* I received informations about the tab, and setted to bundle.
           So thought each tab gives different bundle data to AFragment.
           But since the Adapter is setted only once, this method is not
           called more than once*/

          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

          switch(position){
              case 0:
              AFragment fragment_a = new AFragment();
              fragment_a.setArguments(bundle);
              return fragment_a;

              case 1: //Not really matters
              BFragment fragment_b = new BFragment();
              return fragment_b;

          }
    }   
}
```

My TabLayout code is not so different from other examples.

Thank you again!!!

Comment: You can change title during `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` of `ViewPager`.

Comment: that method works only inside one ViewPager.
I don't mean one ViewPager, but each ViewPager setted to each Tabs.
And each ViewPager needs to represent the tab's information, but since It's inefficient to make every tab's ViewPager, I am looking for ways to let ViewPager receive the information about the Tab when each Tabs are selected. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the Activity needs to be able to listen for changes to the page selected or other events surrounding the ViewPager, then we just need to hook into the ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener on the ViewPager to handle the events:

```
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
// This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
                            }

                            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // set your title here for specic fagment
                //This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.



                            }

                            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    // Called when the scroll state changes: 
        // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING                     

       }
                        });
```

Comment: How will the ViewPager know that the Fragment is changed?

Comment: it needs to automatically refresh when tab is changed. How can it be used efficiently with onTabSelectedListener()?

Comment: well since I won't need onPageScrolled and onPageScrollStateChanged, 
I tried it on onPageSelected.
However, since the tablayout and ViewPager is independent that is, in different layout, tab changing does not effect the ViewPager Listener. ViewPager does not change or refresh itself even thought I select another tab...
I'm sorry but am I missing something..?